# docker newbie: nginx exited with code 1 wp exited with code 0, no SSL

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to learn Docker and run Wordpress on it (Apple silicon).

I found this tutorial
https://dev.to/aschmelyun/build-a-solid-wordpress-dev-environment-with-docker-448j

After setting everything up and trying to start up my local server WP exits and NGINX exits, these are the errors

nginx exited with code 1
wp exited with code 0

wp has no other errors, but nginx has this, seems to be SSL error

```
   nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration

nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/

nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh

nginx | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

nginx | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version

nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh

nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

nginx | 2021/05/08 17:05:32 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/self-signed/wordpress-docker.test.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/self-signed/wordpress-docker.test.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

nginx | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/certs/self-signed/wordpress-docker.test.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/self-signed/wordpress-docker.test.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

nginx exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the README in the nginx/certs directory under your docker root.

You need to put a certificate there, with the name "wordpress-docker.test.pem"

Then this line of the nginx.dockerfile:

```
ADD ./nginx/certs /etc/nginx/certs/self-signed
```

adds it to the nginx directory in the container.

(This is afar as I got at the moment: The "docker-compose up --build site" command no longer has that 'file not found' error.)